# XWPF POI paragraph border color red

Tags: colors, apache-poi, border, paragraph, xwpf

How to change color of paragraph border.
paragraph border color red

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp7xk.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Although `apache poi` `XWPF` provides to set paragraph borders using `XWPFParagraph.setBorder...` methods - for ex. [XWPFParagraph.html#setBorderLeft](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#setBorderLeft-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.Borders-) - it not provides setting border colors upto now. So we need using the underlaying low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` classes.

Paragraph borders are set in paragraph properties (`pPr`). There are paragraph border (`pBdr`) elements having settings for left, top, right and bottom borders. Those  `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` elements then have settings for line type (this is what `apache poi` provides already), line size and line color. The `color` is set as RGB-Hex.

Following example provides a method `void setBorderLeftColor(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String rgb)` to set left border color.

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordParagraphBorderColor {
    
 private static void setBorderLeftColor(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String rgb) {
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr() == null) return; // no paragraph properties = no borders
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getPBdr() == null) return; // no paragraph border 
  if (paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getPBdr().getLeft() == null) return; // no left border
  paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getPBdr().getLeft().setColor(rgb);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Following paragraph with border left and border left color:");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();  
  paragraph.setBorderLeft(Borders.SINGLE);

  setBorderLeftColor(paragraph, "FF0000");

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordParagraphBorderColor.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```